# why does iPa or app file is so smaller than original project?

Tags: xcode, file, size, ipa, .app

I am aware of that .app file in only contains required .o files and which reduce the size of original project. Even 3GB project creates only 30mb of iPA file.

But apart from this what else reduce the project size and make it so small as compare to original projects.